# Writing a custom foreach tag that exposes a nested variable

Tags: jsp, custom-tags

I want to have a custom jsp tag that looks like this:

```
<custom:foreach item="<%=myMap%>">
   Current key: <%= key %>
   Current value: <%= value %>
</custom:foreach>
```

The foreach will loop of the given list / map and expose the key / value in each iteration and evaluate them on the given body content.

I don't know how to expose the key and value variables into the custom foreach tag as Eclipse is telling me that "key cannot be resolved to a variable".

I've searched for almost an hour on google and found the following:

- http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.springsource.com/javax.servlet/com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.0/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagSupport.java/?v=source - the actual source of the jstl foreach. They use pageContent.setAttribute() to expose the variables to the tag.
- [nested el variables for jsp taglibs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202958/nested-el-variables-for-jsp-taglibs): Who is almost asking the same as me
- some .tld configurations with  which did not help at all

I currently have the following:

```
for(Entry<String, String> entry : values.entrySet()) {
   pageContext.setAttribute("key", entry.getKey());
   out.println(getBodyContent().getString());
}
```

(located in doAfterBody()).

Anybody can tell me how to expose the current iteration var inside my tag?

Thanks!

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, does it make any difference on the actual functionality? Shouldn't it work in both ways?

Comment: @BalusC: Well if the guys who ordered this tag want it, i do it... Sometimes arguing with "the upper guys" is not helpful.